# get list of used user functions in php?

Tags: php, function

When using `get_defined_functions()` and `get_declared_classes()` I do get a list of all functions and classes that is included, or loaded, into my site.
But in my case, I have sort of a framework-folder that contains a lot of files, including functions and classes, that are made available for all my projects. It also reduce the need of duplicates.

I load functions like this:

```
foreach(glob('dir/local/*.func.php') as $function_file){include $function_file;}  //  allways load functions from this projects folder
if(defined('use_framework')){  //  if framework is activated, load functions from framework aswell.
    foreach(glob('dir/framework/*.func.php') as $function_file){
        $function_name=explode('.',pathinfo($function_file,PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        if(!function_exists($function_name[0])){include $function_file;}
    }
}
```

Classes is ok since I use `spl_autoload_register()` to load them...

But is there a way to detect what functions is actually been used?
As of now I just keep a list up to date, but thought there might be a more automated way.

Comment: *"what functions is actually been used"* – For that you'd have to execute ***all*** possible code paths of an application, including all `if` and `else` and `include`. It is somewhere between unreliable and impossible to determine statically.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sort-of-answer, and won’t be exactly what you’re looking for:

If you use unit testing, you could generate a code coverage report to make sure that every function has a test that covers all the parts of the code.

However, you could end up with a situation where you have a function that is only used by a test. I guess the only real way to find out would be to search your entire project’s source code for the name of each function.

Comment: so there isn't any `autoloader` for functions?  I guess the list I'm keeping is the way to go then...

Comment: Not as such, no, as functions used like this are used in prodecdual programming. I dare say that you might want to think about using a framework that has systems for commonly used functions, but I appriciate that’s no always possible.

Comment: ok. thanks. I'll be just keeping the functionames in an array, and make sure it's up to date.. not that hard when updating it on the fly...